# How to access custom dataframe accessor's namespace?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

According to Pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html) it is possible to register custom accessors like below:

```py
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("geo")
class GeoAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._validate(pandas_obj)
        self._obj = pandas_obj

    @property
    def center(self):
        lat = self._obj.latitude
        lon = self._obj.longitude
        return (float(lon.mean()), float(lat.mean()))

    def method(self):
        # do something
```

Suppose that there are more accessors with different namespaces. For instance:

- geo2
- geo3

If we'd like to invoke a method from `geo`, for example, we'd do:

```py
df.geo.method() # here we use geo explicitly
```

How could I store/retrieve a namespace to/from a variable?

I am thinking something along the lines of:

```py
df.variable_namespace.method() # variable_namespace could be geo, geo2 etc..
```

What if we'd like to have dynamic behavior as far as namespaces are concerned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider that a variable is responsible for storing a namespace as such:

```py
variable_namespace = 'geo' # or 'geo2', 'geo3' etc.
```

Then, it is possible to achieve dynamic behavior:

```py
df.__getattr__(variable_namespace).method()
```